# XML didn't show HTML in infowindow

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, xml, google-maps

Using MySQL and PHP with Google Maps.

XML Reference:

```
<markers>

    <marker id="1" 
    title="ABC" 
    description="<img src="www.xyz.com/assets/xyz.jpg">
    <br/>description about 2nd point. <br/>
    <a href="www.xyz.com/index.htm">Read More</a>" 
    lat="-33.869843" 
    lng="-151.225769" 
    type="bar" 
    district="xyz" />

</markers>
```

**Infowindow `<div>` supports my HTML, show my title with image and a link to my page:**

```
downloadUrl('https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite
           /json/mapmarkers2.xml', function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
```

Portion to be edit:

> ```
>           var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');
>           var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
>           var details = markerElem.getAttribute('details');
>           var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
>           var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
>               parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
>               parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));
> ```

**Type markers are in different colours**

```
          var text = document.createElement('text');
          text.textContent = address
          infowincontent.appendChild(text);
          var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            label: icon.label
          });
          marker.addListener('click', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
```

Please help me to complete my assignment.

Comment: Are you sure your XML is valid? I get "The Value Of Attribute "description" Associated With An Element Type "marker" Must Not Contain The '<' Character" in some [online validator](http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html). Even at first sight it *looks* terribly wrong :-?

Comment: What is the actual question here? The thing you call "assignment"?

Comment: I am using this same structure: https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/mapmarkers2.xml

Comment: Dear Fuzzzzel, I want to put an image and a link in infowindow.